# Azure WebJob associated with ASP.NET web application cannot access user role from WebJob

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-identity, azure-webjobs

**Background:**
The ASP.NET Web Application manages users, roles and user credit that users spend on their active services. A webjob regularly check which services users are using and update their credits accordingly. The `CreditUpdate` operation performed by the WebJob should also take into account the UserRole when updating the credits.

**Problem:** I cannot access the roles from the web job. On the WebApp the roles are managed and accessed by `ApplicationUserManager` class: `UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id)`. The Problem is the WebJob does cannot access the UserManager `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()` and I don't know how to create a new instance from the WebJob either.

So in short. Having access to the Identity Database and having an instance of an `ApplicationUser`. Any ideas how I can access the user roles associated with it?

Here is the code of my webjob in case it helps. File is `Functions.cs`

```
// This function will be triggered based on the schedule you have set for this WebJob
// This function will enqueue a message on an Azure Queue called queue
[NoAutomaticTrigger]
public static void ManualTrigger(TextWriter log, int value, [Queue("queue")] out string message)
{
    var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var users = db.Users.ToList();
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        //I would like to check user role first
        //if (user.IsInRole("canruletheworld")) {}
        user.updateCredit();
    }

    log.WriteLine("Function is invoked with value={0}", value);
    message = value.ToString();
    log.WriteLine("Following message will be written on the Queue={0}", message);
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the Azure AD Graph aPI ? You can retrieve user roles using it. Let me know if you need some samples.

Comment: That could probably do. But it's more complex than I expected. And seems a bit of an overkill to do it over the network when having the db connection already locally. In addition it would be better if the solution will also work with the local database I normally use during development (on my laptop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just construct a local instance of the UserManager:

```
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```